# How to implement BindableBase to EF6 models?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, t4

What is the correct method to `inject` BindableBase to EF's models? I found some couple years old `T4` templates to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but foreign keys didn't work as wanted. Read from somewhere that T4 will be updated after each EF update, so it would be great to understand it's a way of working. If somebody could just explain the parts of the template to be modified, I could create that on my own.

So what I need is:

```
using Prism.MvvM;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public partial class ModelName : BindableBase
private string _Status
public string Status
{
   get { return _Status; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _Status, value); }
}
```

Implementation for each property.

And I know models should be duplicated in ViewModels in "Pure MVVM" but in this situation, I need this just for keeping views (mostly listviews) updated. The application is made for data processing and handling.

Using WPF, EF 6.4.4(DB First), Prism.Wpf

Comment: What do you mean by `inject`?

Comment: Things should be added when the models are generated. Don't have an idea how that could be done. Manually added code disappears after model refreshed.

Comment: There is a t4 template in your project which is used to generate the model classes. You could edit that. I recommend you jnstead consider the ef model to be a dto. Copy data from a model object to a viewmodel to edit then back to commit. Maje the viewmodel self tracking for changes if you want to edit in a datagrid. Put validation attributes and logic in the viewmodel.